# Как переводить элемент на странице?

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте есть своя локализация для каждого из нужных языков, однако еще есть элементы которые в процессе работы с сайтом подгружаются через XHR. Как мне переводить конкретный элемент на нужный язык?
Уже искал, нашел только перевод для всей страницы, а нужен для конкретного элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Может, это подойдет - https://yandex.ru/dev/translate/doc/dg/concepts/api-keys-docpage/
При подгрузке элементов запрашиваете у api перевод их textnode составляющих. У гугла тоже есть, конечно, - но он, пишут, платный...

Comment: По вашей ссылке пишет, что у yandex тоже платно теперь. Может я не туда посмотрел куда-то